# Where to call the Android Intent handler code in Gluon

Tags: android, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports

Trying to handle the intents that are specified in AndroidManifest.xml. Not sure where to call the Service method that is created. Unlike in native android code where the intents are handled in the activity.
Referring to http://gluonhq.com/handling-android-native-activities-like-a-pro/
tried calling the service in the init method of the main class of the application (But seems like the intent handler methods are not called)

For the Gluon app to receive data from other apps in android

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.nativeeg" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
        <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
         <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
        <application android:label="NativeEg" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
                <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:label="NativeEg" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
                        <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="com.nativeeg.NativeEg"/>
                        <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                         <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>

                </activity>

                <activity android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.PermissionRequestActivity" />
        </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

The Native Service to handle the intent

```
import nativeutility.ReceiveFromApps;
import javafxports.android.FXActivity;
import android.content.Intent;

/**
 *
 * @author Vaishnavi
 */
public class AndroidReceiveFromApps implements ReceiveFromApps{

    @Override
    public void receiveData() {

         Intent intent = FXActivity.getInstance().getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        System.out.println("in handle intent!");
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
           // Handle text being sent
           System.out.println("text data");
        } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            // Handle single image being sent
            System.out.println("image data");
        }
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
          System.out.println("in handle intent!");
        if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
           // Handle multiple images being sent
            System.out.println("multiple image data");
        }
    } else {
        // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
    }     
    }

}
```

Gluon Main class:

```
public class NativeEg extends MobileApplication {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        AppViewManager.registerViewsAndDrawer(this);
        System.out.println("in main");
         Services.get(ReceiveFromApps.class).ifPresent(service -> service.receiveData());

    }
...


package nativeutility;
import com.gluonhq.charm.down.DefaultServiceFactory;
public class ReceiveFromAppsFactory extends DefaultServiceFactory<ReceiveFromApps> {
    public ReceiveFromAppsFactory() {
        super(ReceiveFromApps.class);
    }}
```

Interface

```
package nativeutility;
public interface ReceiveFromApps {
     public void receiveData();
}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the Go Native [sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/go-native) and its [doc](http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/gonative/)? The link you mention refers to an old implementation of Go Native. But you should use the new one, that matches the way the services are implemented in Charm Down.

Comment: Yes, I did look at the above sample and doc but the sample does not have an example of how to handle intents in specific. To give you more context I would like to launch my  Gluon App from other apps (eg from photos app  share files to my app). Able to launch the Gluon app from the Photos app in android but the intent is not being handled

Comment: Can you post your service and full implementation classes, including the package name? The service has to use the exact same package as any other service from Charm Down.

Comment: You can edit your question and post it there. And notice my comment: _The service has to use the exact same package as any other service from Charm Down_

Comment: Interface
package nativeutility;
public interface ReceiveFromApps {
     public void receiveData();
}
DefaultServiceFactory 
package nativeutility;
import com.gluonhq.charm.down.DefaultServiceFactory;
public class ReceiveFromAppsFactory extends DefaultServiceFactory<ReceiveFromApps> {
    public ReceiveFromAppsFactory() {
        super(ReceiveFromApps.class);
    }}
Native Android implementation of ReceiveFromApps is posted in the question

Comment: Hard to read code in between comments, please _edit your question and post it there_.

Comment: Ok thanks for your timely feedbacks and input will try changing the package name

Comment: Make sure you use the same naming convention for the services as in Down. I.e. your service could be named `ReceiveService`, the Factory, `ReceiveServiceFactory`, and the android implementation `AndroidReceiveService`.

Comment: Thank you! the issue was resolved by changing my package name to same package as any other service from Charm Down and renaming the service class names. The intent handler code is being called now